# Passing sensitive data through to the ui

Tags: security, facebook-graph-api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm working on an implementation of the Facebook api and I'm to the point that i can fetch a users pages and would now like to display these to the user so they can select where to send the post. These page objects have an access token on them to verify requests with Facebook and intuition tells me you wouldn't want to send these through to the ui then back again. I could just make 2 calls when sending and receiving, filter the results to remove the access tokens, then when receiving a request make another call to the api and filter the page results by id.

I'm curious though if theres a way to get around making 2 api requests and reduce overall requests to the api and keep the usage down.

Comment: So your app has a server-side component, and that’s where you make your API requests from? Then why send the tokens to the client in the first place, to let the user make their choice which page to post to, you only need page name and id.

Comment: Yes, as I've thought about it I'm just going to request the data, filter out the access token, send the data through to the front end. Then when the user has made their choice it will be submitted with the page id, I will then just make the same api request again and grab the page access token. I was trying to get away from making excessive api requests

Comment: You could just store the page tokens in the session, when you get the list of pages - then you don’t need to make a second API request after the user made their choice.

Comment: is a session secure? I'll start looking into laravel sessions

Comment: Yes, session data is tied to a specific client, and never leaves the server. Only thge session ID is passed between client and server.

Comment: @CBroe if you post your second comment as an answer i would accept it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could just store the page tokens in the session, when you get the list of pages - then you don’t need to make a second API request after the user made their choice.

(Session data is tied to a specific client, and never leaves the server. Only thge session ID is passed between client and server.)